# iPhone. Is it possible to load a video file and select a specific frame?

Tags: iphone, video

Is it possible to load a short video file and - once loaded - select a specific frame and display that frame in a view? If there is no native support for this, how about an open source alternative?

Thanks in advance.

-Doug

Answer (score 0):

### I think that in iphone programming you're stuck with the fullscreen video solution proposed by apple. You could write your own controller to do it differently, but i think it could be difficult to achieve good performances and you're cut out of the app-store for sure.

edit:

looks like in iphone sdk 3.2 apple added something for you:

> The MPMoviePlayerController class
>   defines an interface for managing the
>   playback of a movie. Playback occurs
>   either in full-screen mode or in a
>   custom view that is vended by the
>   movie player controller. You can
>   incorporate the view into your own
>   view hierarchies or use a
>   MPMoviePlayerViewController object to
>   manage the presentation for you.

and again

> Behavior in iPhone OS 3.1 and Earlier
>   In iPhone OS 3.1 and earlier, this
>   class implemented a full-screen movie
>   player only. After creating the movie
>   player and initializing it with a
>   single movie file, you called the play
>   method to present the movie. (The
>   definition of the play method has
>   since moved out of this class and into
>   the MPMediaPlayback protocol.) The
>   movie player object itself handled the
>   actual presentation of the movie
>   content.

i haven't tested it yet but have a look at the official documentation under MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference, it may help.

Comment: isn't SDK 3.2 still under NDA ;)